# Function ec2.snapshots.all not iterate boto3 lambda

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, lambda, boto3

I am using boto3, for list all snapshots.
But when I use function ec2.snapshots.all(), and then try iterate with a for, it's not working.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from boto3 import resource

REGION = "us-east-1"

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    ec2 = resource("ec2", region_name=REGION)
    all_snapshots = ec2.snapshots.all()
    for snapshot in all_snapshots:
        print("SnapshotIteration")
```

The result is the next:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "2017-03-07T00:08:56.583Z 3faed105-02ca-11e7-b637-cfb921e4e3cc Task timed out after 3.00 seconds"
}
```

Comment: How many snapshots do you have? I guess it is way too many. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I agree with @helloV - how long does it take to run "aws ec2 describe-snapshots" on the command line for you?  We have quite a few and it took about 15 seconds for that to come back.  Why is your timeout only 3 seconds?

Comment: I did not know that the function returned all public snapshots. I had tested by increasing the timeout to 30 seconds but obviously not enough. I applied a filter indicating my owner-id as indicated by John Rotenstein and now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect it is listing all publicly-available snapshots, which can be quite a lot. It is better to limit it to snapshots for which you are the owner.

The [`describe-snapshots()`](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_snapshots) function takes an `OwnerIds` parameter that can scope-down the return value.

Here's an example from the [boto3 snapshot documentation](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.ServiceResource.Snapshot) that shows how to use a filter on the `snapshots` iterator:

```
snapshot_iterator = ec2.snapshots.filter(
    DryRun=True|False,
    SnapshotIds=[
        'string',
    ],
    OwnerIds=[
        'string',
    ],
    RestorableByUserIds=[
        'string',
    ],
    Filters=[
        {
            'Name': 'string',
            'Values': [
                'string',
            ]
        },
    ],
    NextToken='string',
    MaxResults=123
)
```

That might help.

Comment: I did not know that the function returned all public snapshots. I applied a filter indicating my owner-id and now it works. Thank you very much.